# Synthetic and simple way to forward arguments to pure functions?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to cover all my application **state** using dedicated **selectors**.
Each slice of my application state is handled by their own selectors.

---

The **problem** is that, sometimes I want to access those "slices selectors" from parent ones (those handling a bigger slice) in a DRY and KISS (**factored** and **simple**) way.

---

I tried importing smaller selectors to forward them the needed slice of the state.

For instance, an application storing fruits and toys in a store:

```
const state = {
  fruits: [
    {
      type: 'banana',
      quantity: 8
    },
    {
      type: 'strawberry',
      quantity: 42
    }
  ],
  toys: [
    {
      name: 'Puzzle',
      size: '12cm'
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a selector retrieving a fruit, filtered by `type` from `state.fruits`, needed slice of the state :

```
// fruitSelectors.js
export const getFilteredFruit = (fruits, type) =>
    fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.type === type)
```

And I would like to use this selector from the state itself (bigger slice), while abstracting the existence of the smaller selectors.

For instance:

```
// stateSelectors.js
import { getFilteredFruit as getFilteredFruitChild }
    from './fruitSelectors.js'

const getFruits = state => state.fruits

export const getFilteredFruit = (state, type) =>
    getFilteredFruitChild(getFruits(state), type)
```

The purpose here, is to reuse the selectors in order to lift the function to any slice of the state without duplicating the code for each depth.

But I find it somewhat verbose to create an `import` `alias` for each existing functions.

---

### Is there a simpler solution to achieve this or an existing alternative ?

Comment: What you are looking for is called *lenses*. They're quite powerful, but can also be quite confusing if you dive deeper into their type system…

Comment: I didn't know about the ***lenses***, I will investigate in this direction. I thank you for this hint.

Comment: This question is quite consteucted, `getFruits(state)` isnt shorter / faster / better than `state.fruits`.

Comment: @JonasWilms I'd say the advantage is that `getFilteredFruitsFromState` can be constructed by composing `getFilteredFruits` with `getFruitsFromState`, but the naming here is quite confusing.

Comment: You are right, I edited the functions name for more clarity.

Comment: Here is an interesting article about lenses: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/lenses-b85976cb0534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further readings about the `lenses`, that was advised by the comments.

I finally found a solution that is maybe not as powerful as the lenses, but that solve my problem and is a lot simpler.

Instead of doing :

```
// stateSelectors.js
import { getFilteredFruit as getFilteredFruitChild }
    from './fruitSelectors.js'

const getFruits = state => state.fruits

export const getFilteredFruit = (state, type) =>
    getFilteredFruitChild(getFruits(state), type)
```

We can modify the import and get a workaround like this :

```
// stateSelectors.js
import * as fromFruits from './fruitSelectors.js'

const getFruits = state => state.fruits

export const getFilteredFruit = (state, type) =>
    fromFruits.getFilteredFruit(getFruits(state), type)
```

I found this from the courses ["Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux"](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) by Dan Abramov, more precisely on the course named ["Redux: Colocating Selectors with Reducers"](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers)

Comment: Oh, I didn't think you only had a problem with the alias…